# Flyway migration in Development and Production

Tags: maven, database-migration, flyway

I searching for an way to do a different migration in production and development.

I want to create a Spring Webapplication with Maven.
In development i want to update database schema AND load test data.
In production when a new version of the application is deployed i want only change the schema and don't load test data.

My first idea was to save the schema update and insert statements into different folders.

I think every body has solved this problem and can help me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 9):

Basically, you have two options:

You could use different locations for your migrations in your flyway.locations property, i.e.:

for Test

```
flyway.locations=sql/structure,sql/test
```

for Production

```
flyway.locations=sql/structure
```

That way, you include your test data in the sql/test folder. You would have to take care with numbering, of course.

The second option (the one I prefer), is don't include test data in your migrations at all.

Rather, create your testdata any way you want and create an sql-dump of this data, which you keep separate from your migrations.

This works best if you have a separate database (instance, schema, whatever) containing your pristine testdata, where you apply each migration as part of your build process. This build job could then create a dump always matching the current migration.

When preparing your test machine, you first apply your migrations, then you load the contents of the matching dump.

I think this is a lot cleaner than the first version, especially because your test data can be prepared using other tools (your application) and has not to be handcoded.

Comment: *...don't include test data in your migrations at all.* I like it.